# Certain commands not accessible with PHPs exec(), but work with Ruby's 'System' command

Tags: php, ruby, shell

On my local machine, i can run the following command in a rails application from a controller, through google chrome:

`system 'say hello dan'`

This produces the expected output - the 'say' program on my mac speaks "hello dan".

Running the same command from a controller in a PHP application, or indeed any php script through google chrome, and there is no output.

`exec('say hello dan');` or `exec('/usr/bin/say hello dan');` both do not work.

I checked on the permissions, but apache is running as the same user as i am.

Running a script containing that code from the command line however, works!

Can anyone offer any insight why certain programs aren't working? Other commands such as `afplay` and other standard commands in /usr/bin are working just fine.

Comment: are you sure it's running with the same user? `whoami` ?

Comment: Yep definitely `danmatthews` same as my bash login.

Comment: Adding 2>&1 to the end gets me this error: `dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib`

Answer (score 2):

Your server might be configured to use PHP in safe mode. Safe mode restricts exec() as follows:

"You can only execute executables within the safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical reasons it's currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable. escapeshellcmd() is executed on the argument of this function."

Comment: Thanks, checked phpinfo and safe mode is disabled.